# Ensure Ionic Angular UI has redrawn before kicking off processor intensive task

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an angular app within the ionic framework which has an encrypted database. The step of opening the database is an intensive task. (up to 6000ms on a typical device).

I have a `Login` button on the page which sets a flag in the controller "Data.Loading = true".

Within the on-page ng-template there is a block

```
<div ng-show="Data.Loading">Please Wait</div>
```

The code which "logs in" is as follows:

```
    $scope.Login = function() {
        if ($scope.IsCorrect($scope.Data.Password)) {
           $scope.Data.Loading = true;
           $scope.OpenAndContinue();
        }
    }

    $scope.OpenAndContinue = function(){
        MyDatabase.open().then(function() {
             $scope.Data.Loading = false;
             $rootScope.Display.Menu = true;
             $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                  disableAnimate: true,
                  disableBack: true,
                  historyRoot: true
             });
             $state.go("app.home")
        })
    }
```

The problem with the above is that the UI is *NOT* particularly responsive. On this page.  In fact it is downright slow - especially compared to numerous other buttons within the app.

The view takes a second or two to update and say "please wait" then another couple seconds to actually finish opening the database.

If I accept that the core-function of opening an encrypted database is sufficiently complex as to prevent opening quickly, I would at the very least like the view to respond to a user's tap *instantly* in order to let them know 
that the thing isn't broken.

I have tried a number of different published angular fixes.

```
    $scope.Login = function() {
        if ($scope.IsCorrect($scope.Data.Password)) {
           $scope.Data.Loading = true;
           $timeout($scope.OpenAndContinue);
           //$timeout($scope.OpenAndContinue, 0, false);
           //$timeout($scope.OpenAndContinue, 250, false);
        }
    }

    $scope.Login = function() {
        if ($scope.IsCorrect($scope.Data.Password)) {
           $scope.Data.Loading = true;
           $scope.$evalAsync($scope.OpenAndContinue);
        }
    }

    $scope.Login = function() {
        if ($scope.IsCorrect($scope.Data.Password)) {
           $scope.Data.Loading = true;
            $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl("templates/modals/login.html", {
                scope: $scope,
                animation: 'scale-in',
                backdropClickToClose: false,
                hardwareBackButtonClose: false
            })
            .then($scope.OpenAndContinue);
        }
    }
```

Nothing I've tried so far gives the "responsiveness" that I'd expect from a button tap. Nor the snappiness I've seen elsewhere in the APP.

Is there anything else I can do to make sure the login feels "snappy"?

Even the modal doesn't have that "snap" feeling.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly - it seems that the answer was unobtainable based on the information I gave.

The function `$scope.IsCorrect` contained a call to another function `$rootScope.$broadcast('myapp.login')`

There was an event listener elsewhere in the APP that opened the database itself (thereby doubling processor usage in those few milliseconds *and* running before the $apply() updates as handled in the code above.)

I eventually found the additional call to "opendatabase" by adding a `console.trace()` command to the code that opened the database. This allowed me to see a full stack trace at that point in time, and determine that something else was causing the performance problem.

StackOverflow penalizes users for deleting questions, so I've decided not to kill this Q&A - hopefully someone can find something useful in this.